# How to read each features in a large geojson

Tags: node.js, json, geojson

I need to take data from a Geojson file and insert some of them in a database.
Problem is: the file is 2.4Gb so Node.js can't read it like that.

I tried to use some json streaming modules with no success (big-json) (stream-json).
The modules expect an array of objects, however, a geojson is just an object with an array of objects inside.

Module expect :

```
[
{
  'name': '',
  'hello': ''
},
{
  'name': '',
  'hello': ''
},
...thousands of objects
]
```

But I have :

```
{
  'type':'FeatureCollection',
  'features':[ ...thousand of objects... ]
}
```

I tried with stream-json :

```
const fs = require('fs')
const {parser} = require('stream-json')
const {chain}  = require('stream-chain')
const {pick}   = require('stream-json/filters/Pick')
const {streamValues} = require('stream-json/streamers/StreamValues')

const pipeline = chain([
  fs.createReadStream('myHugeFile.json'), //2.4Gb
  parser(),
  pick({filter: /^\d+\.features\.\d+/}),
  streamValues()
])
pipeline.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data)
})
pipeline.on('end', () => {
  console.log(`Done`)
})
```

It never goes to the `on('data')`.
I want to get all feature objects in the 'features' array.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [stream-json/filters/Pick](https://github.com/uhop/stream-json/wiki/Pick) provides an example useful for a GeoJSON file.

Here's how you'd read `features` from `myHugeFile.geojson`:

```js
const Pick = require('stream-json/filters/Pick');
const {streamArray} = require('stream-json/streamers/StreamArray');
const {chain} = require('stream-chain');
const fs = require('fs');

const pipeline = chain([
  fs.createReadStream('myHugeFile.geojson'),
  Pick.withParser({filter: 'features'}),
  streamArray()
]);

pipeline.on('data', data => console.log(data));
```

Note that the `pipeline.on` method is called asynchronously. So if you are writing `data` to an array and try reading this array immediately, it will be empty.

The `end` event is triggered once reading is complete (taking several minutes, potentially):

```
pipeline.on('end', () => console.log('End!'));
```